# Numpy ndarray compression methods in python

Tags: python, numpy, compression, numpy-ndarray

I'm writing a script to transfer 3 dimensional arrays from one PC to other using sockets so I want to compress it by the sender side and decompress it in the receiver side.
The thing is that this is a lot of bytes to transfer so I've been thinking on compressing the numpy ndarray to have less bytes to transfer.
I'm transferring images with a lot of similar neighbors which indicates that compression can be done.

Any idea on how I can compress this ?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed

Comment: This saves the compression to a file ... not something that I need

Comment: Specialized image compression algorithms will generally give better compression than a general-purpose compressor. So maybe try converting the image data back to a PNG, that's easy to do from Numpy with PIL, although PIL doesn't give you full access to all of PNG's compression options.